# VCF issue using Mitty

Tags: python, bash, simulation, vcf-vcard

I have simulated VCF files using Mitty "simulate-variants" and now I am trying to simulate reads (60X and an average length of 50 if possible) using Mitty again.
There is my script that I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


FASTA=/fast/users/me/data/human_g1k_v37.fasta
SAMPLEVCF=/fast/users/me/sim_VCF/VCF1/simtest.vcf.gz
SAMPLENAME=sample1
REGION_BED=/fast/users/me/bedfile/all_chr1.bed
FILTVCF=sample1-filt.vcf.gz
READMODEL=old-Garvan.pkl
COVERAGE=60
READ_GEN_SEED=7
FASTQ_PREFIX=sample1-reads
READ_CORRUPT_SEED=8


mitty -v4 filter-variants \
    ${SAMPLEVCF} \
    ${SAMPLENAME} \
    ${REGION_BED} \
    - \
    2> vcf-filter.log | bgzip -c > ${FILTVCF}

tabix -p vcf ${FILTVCF}



mitty -v4 generate-reads \
    ${FASTA} \
    ${FILTVCF} \
    ${SAMPLENAME} \
    ${REGION_BED} \
    ${READMODEL} \
    ${COVERAGE} \
    ${READ_GEN_SEED} \
    >(gzip > ${FASTQ_PREFIX}1.fq.gz) \
    ${FASTQ_PREFIX}_lq.txt \
    --fastq2 >(gzip > ${FASTQ_PREFIX}2.fq.gz) \
    --threads 2



mitty -v4 corrupt-reads \
    ${READMODEL} \
    ${FASTQ_PREFIX}1.fq.gz >(gzip > ${FASTQ_PREFIX}_corrupt1.fq.gz) \
    ${FASTQ_PREFIX}_lq.txt \
    ${FASTQ_PREFIX}_corrupt-lq.txt \
    ${READ_CORRUPT_SEED} \
    --fastq2-in ${FASTQ_PREFIX}2.fq.gz \
    --fastq2-out >(gzip > ${FASTQ_PREFIX}_corrupt2.fq.gz) \
    --threads 2
```

And here is the multiples errors output that I get when I try to run it:

```
DEBUG:mitty.cli:Mitty version 2.28.3
DEBUG:root:Found model old-Garvan.pkl in builtins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/bin/mitty", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mitty==2.28.3', 'console_scripts', 'mitty')()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mitty/cli.py", line 162, in generate_reads
    threads=threads, seed=seed)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mitty/simulation/readgenerate.py", line 74, in process_multi_threaded
    vcf_df = vio.load_variant_file(vcf_fname, sample_name, bed_fname)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mitty/lib/vcfio.py", line 47, in load_variant_file
    vcf_fp = pysam.VariantFile(fname, mode)
  File "pysam/libcbcf.pyx", line 3479, in pysam.libcbcf.VariantFile.__init__ (pysam/libcbcf.c:51398)
  File "pysam/libcbcf.pyx", line 3669, in pysam.libcbcf.VariantFile.open (pysam/libcbcf.c:54088)
ValueError: invalid file `b'sample1-filt.vcf.gz'` (mode='b'r'') - is it VCF/BCF format?
DEBUG:mitty.cli:Mitty version 2.28.3
Usage: mitty corrupt-reads [OPTIONS] MODELFILE FASTQ1_IN FASTQ1_OUT SIDECAR_IN
                           SIDECAR_OUT SEED
Try "mitty corrupt-reads --help" for help.

Error: Invalid value for "SIDECAR_IN": Path "sample1-reads_lq.txt" does not exist.
```

I guess I have, at leat, two error in my code. When I get rid of the "corrupt-reads part" I still have the first issue and I don't know what to do about those VCF file.

Do anyone know why I am getting those ?

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear. Your `sample1-filt.vcf.gz` does not seems to be a properly formatte VCF file. Take a look at it and check it is a valid VCF file. If it is valid, try to give the uncompressed file (in reality, your file is not a VCF, it is a bzip file that encloses a VCF).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried that and it's not changing anything. I think Mitty is overwriting the file `sample1-filt.vcf.gz` with the script that I am using: It's a VCF file before I run it and then it becomes a binary file.. I might do something wrong with Mitty I guess but I really don't know what.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hummm... which kund of binary? Run `file` on it to try to discover something.
If the file is overwritten, could it be that the parameter is misplaced? Check that all your variables contain what they must contain. And check that there are no spaces in the contents. Better: quote all your variables. Always.